# Linq query using list output as input

Tags: linqpad

I am using Linqpad and have odata connection setup.
I have a query as follows

QUERY1

```
void Main()
{var a = from cpuid in Computers
where cpuid.DnsHostName == "xyz"
select new {
    ID = cpuid.TechnicalProductsHosted.Select (x => new { Id = x.Id }),
    System_Dept = cpuid.SystemDepartment,
    };
Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

The output : it returns 4 ids but one department which is common among all four id's. When i query otherway round i.e

QUERY2

```
var a = from id in TechnicalProducts
where id.Id == "ID-15784"
select new
{System_Dept = id.Computers.Select(x => x.SystemDepartment),
Support_Team = id.Computers.Select(x => x.SupportTeam)
};
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

The output : 4 departments for the id. I wish to have the whole list of departments in the first case. How is it possible? In query 1 Can i take id as input for System Department and query it somehow?

the output samples
[image]

Comment: What would be the intent of the query? For a given computer, return the IDs of the hosted products and what? Maybe if you provide a short sample with how the result of the query should look like, it might help.

Comment: Please check the code wity with updated output...